# Buttons and Links on My Website Don't Work After Updating Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

After the homepage on which I used HTML5 template was updated to Google Chrome version 85, its buttons and links became inoperable. It worked well in Chrome's 84 and earlier versions. Works fine in Opera Browser.

To view the issue, update Google Chrome to the latest version and check the buttons and links on the "https://bbturk.com" page.

You can find the files of the template I use here: https://freehtml5.co/preview/?item=black-one-page-free-html5-bootstrap-template-for-landing-pages

Why does this problem occur and how can I fix it?

Thanks in advance to everyone who will answer and take care.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `z-index` of your header try to do that:

```
#fh5co-header.navbar-fixed-top{

    position: fixed !important;
    margin-top: 0px;
    top: 0;
    z-index:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>#fh5co-header.navbar-fixed-top{

             position: fixed !important;
             margin-top: 0px;
             top: 0;
             z-index:0;
        }
  </style>
```

I tried this and it worked, Thank you so much.